# How exactly should I implement a shuffle or random-number algorithm for an array to display quotes in random order?

Tags: c++, random, shuffle

I already know there's answers for this kind of thing, but I don't really know how to implement them in my code. Also, I would like to refrain from using any more functions unless neccessary. 
Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
 unsigned seed;
 seed = 1;
 srand(seed);
 std::string starFox[8];
 int x[8];
 starFox[0] = "Do a barrel roll!";
 starFox[1] = "Try a somersault!";
 starFox[2] = "Use bombs wisely!";
 starFox[3] = "Something is wrong with the G-diffuser";
 starFox[4] = "Can't let you do that, Star Fox";
 starFox[5] = "Hey Einstein, I'm on your side";
 starFox[6] = "Whoa! help me!";
 starFox[7] = "Daddy screamed REAL good before he died!";

 for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
 {
  int y = 0 + rand() % 8;
  x[i] = y;

  if (x[i-1]!=y || x[i-2]!=y || x[i-3]!=y || x[i-4]!=y || x[i-5]!=y || x[i-6]!=y || x[i-7]!=y)
  {//now I need to make a statement that makes sure each number appears once.
   std::cout << starFox[y] << "\n";}
 }
 std::cout << '\n';

 return 0;
}
```

So, what should I alter about this code to make it generate random numbers each time the program executes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133942/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pick-a-random-card-from-a-deck-when-some-cards among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeding the same value every time you run, so you'll always get the same pseudo-random sequence.  Try this:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [std::random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/)

```
// Shuffle
std::random_shuffle(starFox, starFox + 8);

// And write to standard output
std::copy(starFox, starFox + 8,
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but where would I put these in the program? And what should I include in order to avoid errors?

Comment: @Mr. Czar: This code will replace your for loop.  You'll need `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Oh, and `#include <iterator>`

Answer (score 1):

Solution to random shuffle:

- Put all the numbers you want to shuffle into a container (vector) (Call it the src)
- Create an empty container that is ordered to put the numbers as you randomly select them (Call it the dst)
- while (src is not empty)

  - Generate a random number [0,len(src))  (Note not inclusive)
  - Remove the element at src[Rand]
  - Put the removed element into dst

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an array to keep track of which ones have been seen, how about if you store the quotes in a list and simply remove a quote after it has been used.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [solution](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/misc/random-shuffle.html) for random shuffle.